# Vue props "validation" on a wrapper "BaseButton" component prop that checks for a parent's $attrs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, scope, vue-component

I have a BaseButton wrapper component that is used throughout the application. I want to add a `gaLabel` prop with a validator or some way to validate that considers the parent's `$attrs` for aria-labels. It should basically be required, unless there is an aria-label on the parent component. Here is an example of the BaseButton wrapper component:

```
<template>
    <button
        :class="{ 'focus:highlight': !noFocusHighlight }"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        :type="type"
        class="input-transition"
        v-on="$listeners"
    >
        <slot/>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'BaseButton',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: {
        noFocusHighlight: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        gaLabel: {
            validator: prop => <SOME VALIDATION HERE>,
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            validator: value => ['button', 'submit', 'reset'].includes(value),
            default: 'button',
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I know I do not have access to `this` inside the props validator and therefore I do not have access to `$attrs`, but does anyone see a way that I can keep this component as is, but have the `gaLabel` prop consider the parent's $attrs for the existence of an aria-label?

Many of the usages of this component have an aria-label, but not all and it's not necessary for all. The gaLabel and aria-label end up saying the same thing for different purposes, so I could in theory allow the aria-label to be the default for gaLabel and otherwise require a gaLabel. I would like to extract this logic to this component so if someone were to use it and set an aria-label, they wouldn't need to consider the gaLabel prop.

Comment: Sorry man, doesn't look like it's possible. The other solution would be to manually throw an error in the `created()` lifecycle hook where you have access to `this`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, but wanted to throw it out there just in case. I may have another solution, so I'll update if I find a way to solve it outside of validation.